# Proving relative order is preserved (Dafny)

Tags: dafny

Here's a simple algorithm that returns the even numbers in an array of ints:

```
predicate IsEven(n: int)
{
    n % 2 == 0
}

method FindEvenNumbers(arr: array<int>) returns (evenNumbers: array<int>)
    // All even numbers in the input are in the output
    ensures forall x :: x in arr[..] && IsEven(x) ==> x in evenNumbers[..];
    // If a number is not in the input, it's also not in the output 
    ensures forall x :: x !in arr[..] ==> x !in evenNumbers[..]
    // Relative order of even numbers is preserved ???
{
    var evenList: seq<int> := [];
    for i := 0 to arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= |evenList| <= i
        invariant forall x :: x in arr[..i] && IsEven(x) ==> x in evenList[..]
        invariant forall x :: x !in arr[..i] ==> x !in evenList
    {
        if IsEven(arr[i])
        {
            evenList := evenList + [arr[i]];
        }
    }

    evenNumbers := new int[|evenList|](i requires 0 <= i < |evenList| => evenList[i]);
    assert evenList == evenNumbers[..];
}
```

This code verifies. But I would like to prove that it preserves the relative order of the numbers in the output wrt their order in the input. So `FindEvenNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4])` is `[2, 4]` not `[4, 2]`. I'm having an incredibly hard time proving this.

Here are a few things I tried:

The following version does not verify, because the last loop invariant doesn't hold:

```
method FindEvenNumbers(arr: array<int>) returns (evenNumbers: array<int>)
    // All even numbers in the input are in the output
    ensures forall x :: x in arr[..] && IsEven(x) ==> x in evenNumbers[..];
    // If a number is not in the input, it's also not in the output 
    ensures forall x :: x !in arr[..] ==> x !in evenNumbers[..]
    // Relative order of even numbers is preserved
    ensures forall k, l :: 0 <= k < l < evenNumbers.Length && evenNumbers.Length >= 2 ==> 
            exists n, m :: 0 <= n < m < arr.Length && evenNumbers[k] == arr[n] && evenNumbers[l] == arr[m]
{
    var evenList: seq<int> := [];
    for i := 0 to arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= |evenList| <= i
        invariant forall x :: x in arr[..i] && IsEven(x) ==> x in evenList[..]
        invariant forall x :: x !in arr[..i] ==> x !in evenList
        invariant forall k, l :: 0 <= k < l < |evenList| && |evenList| >= 2 ==> 
                  exists n, m :: 0 <= n < m < i && evenList[k] == arr[n] && evenList[l] == arr[m]
    {
        if IsEven(arr[i])
        {
            evenList := evenList + [arr[i]];
        }
    }

    evenNumbers := new int[|evenList|](i requires 0 <= i < |evenList| => evenList[i]);
    assert evenList == evenNumbers[..];
}
```

The situation calls for something to be remembered on previous iterations, so a recursive form might be better. Here is another version that uses a recursive function:

```
method FindEvenNumbers(arr: array<int>) returns (evenNumbers: array<int>)
    // All even numbers in the input are in the output
    ensures forall x :: x in arr[..] && IsEven(x) ==> x in evenNumbers[..];
    // If a number is not in the input, it's also not in the output 
    ensures forall x :: x !in arr[..] ==> x !in evenNumbers[..]
    // Relative order of even numbers is preserved?
    ensures evenNumbers[..] == filter(arr[..], IsEven)
{
    var evenList: seq<int> := filter(arr[..], IsEven);
    evenNumbers := new int[|evenList|](i requires 0 <= i < |evenList| => evenList[i]);
    assert evenList == evenNumbers[..];
}

function filter<T>(s: seq<T>, p: T -> bool) : seq<T>
    ensures forall x :: x !in s ==> x !in filter(s, p)
    ensures forall x :: x in s && p(x) ==> x in filter(s, p)
    ensures |s| > 0 && p(s[0]) <==> |s| > 0  && filter(s, p) == [s[0]] + filter(s[1..], p)
{
    if s == [] then []
    else 
        if p(s[0]) then 
            [s[0]] + filter(s[1..], p)
        else filter(s[1..], p)
}
```

This verifies, and it sort of achieves the goal. But this makes the filter function be part of the public API: one needs to look at the postconditions of filter in order to understand that it uses prefix/tail call form to build the sequence; from this observation we can guess that order is preserved, maybe? But, more importantly, it forces to get rid of the iterative algorithm in favor of the functional one.

So two questions:

1. How do I prove that the original iterative algorithm preserves the relative order of the elements without changing it entirely?
2. Does the second (functional) version really prove that the relative order is preserved? I am not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove original iterative version preserve relative order, we need to maintain indices from which evenList elements are drawn. Since these indices required only for proof, let's use ghost variable to declare them.

`ghost var indices: seq<int> := [];`

Finally to prove required post-condition, we need to maintain certain loop invariants namely

```
invariant |evenList| == |indices|
invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < |indices| ==> indices[k] < i
invariant forall k, l :: 0 <= k < l < |indices| ==> indices[k] < indices[l]
invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < |evenList| ==> 0 <= indices[k] < i <= arr.Length && arr[indices[k]] == evenList[k]
invariant forall k, l :: 0 <= k < l < |evenList| ==>
  exists n, m :: 0 <= n < m < i && evenList[k] == arr[n] && evenList[l] == arr[m]
```

With these in place, dafny is able to verify the falling post condition.

```
predicate IsEven (n: int)
{
  n % 2 == 0
}

method FindEvenNumbers (arr: array<int>)
  returns (evenNumbers: array<int>)
  ensures forall x :: x in arr[..] && IsEven(x) ==> x in evenNumbers[..];
  ensures forall x :: x !in arr[..] ==> x !in evenNumbers[..]
    ensures forall k, l :: 0 <= k < l < evenNumbers.Length ==>
    exists n, m :: 0 <= n < m < arr.Length && evenNumbers[k] == arr[n] && evenNumbers[l] == arr[m]
{
    var evenList: seq<int> := [];
    ghost var indices: seq<int> := [];

    for i := 0 to arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= arr.Length
        invariant 0 <= |evenList| <= i
        invariant forall x :: x in arr[..i] && IsEven(x) ==> x in evenList[..]
        invariant forall x :: x !in arr[..i] ==> x !in evenList
        invariant |evenList| == |indices|
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < |indices| ==> indices[k] < i
        invariant forall k, l :: 0 <= k < l < |indices| ==> indices[k] < indices[l]
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < |evenList| ==> 0 <= indices[k] < i <= arr.Length && arr[indices[k]] == evenList[k]
        invariant forall k, l :: 0 <= k < l < |evenList| ==>
           exists n, m :: 0 <= n < m < i && evenList[k] == arr[n] && evenList[l] == arr[m]
    {
        if IsEven(arr[i])
        {
          evenList := evenList + [arr[i]];
          indices := indices + [i];
        }
    }

    evenNumbers := new int[|evenList|](i requires 0 <= i < |evenList| => evenList[i]);
    assert evenList == evenNumbers[..];
}
```

I believe your functional version does prove relative order because of third postcondition of filter which restricts first element of result of filter.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, and it opened up a door to strategies for proofs!